# How do you evaluate limit of $\frac{\sqrt{a+x} - \sqrt a}{x\sqrt a(\sqrt{a+x})}$ when $x$ tends to $0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried rationalization method where we multiply both the numerator and denominator with appropriate opposite factor of numerator. But I could only get $\frac{1}{\sqrt {a^2+ax}(2 \sqrt {a + \sqrt x)}}$. But the final solution in textbook says it should be $\frac{1}{2a^{3/2}}$. Please help.

Comment: Please put dollar signs ($) around your math formulas to TeXify them, @zaidKnight.

Comment: oh missed that .TY

Comment: is it right so?

Comment: yes. that looks proper now!!

Answer (score 7):

\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{a+x}-\sqrt{a}}{x\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+x}} &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a+x-a}{x\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+x}(\sqrt{a+x}+\sqrt{a})}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+x}(\sqrt{a+x}+\sqrt{a})}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a}(2\sqrt{a})}\\
&=\frac{1}{2a^\frac32}\end{align}

Comment: Oh! got it now. Thank you Siong. upvoted your answer but it wont show as my reputation is less than required.

Comment: no worries about reputation, glad you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. Put
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{x+a}\implies f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+a}}.
$$
by the chain rule. Then the limit can be expressed as
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\times \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}f'(0)\times \frac{1}{f(0)}=\frac{1}{2a^{3/2}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Easier solution:** Write $y=\sqrt{x+a}$ and $b=\sqrt{a}$, then

\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{a+x}-\sqrt{a}}{x\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+x}} &= \lim_{y \to b}\frac{y-b}{by(y^2-b^2)}\\&=\lim_{y \to b}\frac{1}{by(y+b)}\\
&= \frac{1}{2b^3}=\frac{1}{2a\sqrt{a}}\end{align}